# Add custom domain for customer in azure web app and add let's encript certificate automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ssl, lets-encrypt

We offer services to help local business to gather more reviews on platforms like Google or Facebook. Each customer has a kind of own site, hosted by us. But technically it runs on **one** Azure Web App. Each customer has for example a url like following: https://portal.your-voting.com/freds-bike-shop. We want go give our customers the opportunity to configure their own domain in the backend. For example : https://review.freds-bike.shop. Also the SSL certificate from Let's Encript for Azure should work with the custom domain.

How do i programmatically add custom domains for my azure web app?
How do i automatically get and install the Let's Encript certificates for the customer domains?

At the moment we use the Let's Encript Site Extension and C# als programming Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i programmatically add custom domains for my azure web app?

You could leverage [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-management-libraries-for-net-generally-available-now/) and follow [Getting Started with App - Manage Web App With Domain Ssl - in .Net](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-dotnet-manage-web-apps-with-custom-domains) for binding a custom domain name to the Web App as follows:

```
app1.Update()
.DefineHostnameBinding()
.WithThirdPartyDomain("{yourdomain.com}")
.WithSubDomain("{your-subdomain}")
.WithDnsRecordType(CustomHostNameDnsRecordType.CName)
.Attach()
.Apply();
```

> How do i automatically get and install the Let's Encrypt certificates for the customer domains?

Here is a similar approach for using powershell automation for azure web app with Let's Encrypt certificate, details you could [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/01/25/azure-web-app-with-lets-encrypt-certificate-powershell-automation/) about the [CreateLetsEncryptWebApp.ps1](https://github.com/hansenms/LetsEncryptWebApp/blob/master/CreateLetsEncryptWebApp.ps1) with the following steps:

> a) create an Azure Web App
>
> b) generate a certificate from Let's Encrypt
>
> c) bind the certificate to the Web App with a custom domain name

For using Let's Encript Site Extension, you need to register an Azure AD app and configure the relevant Web App settings, details you could follow [here](https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension).

Comment: Thanks, thats a lot of help! :)